# Javascript doesn't work on Android

Tags: javascript, android

I have a very basic app that just load JavaScript to a webview.

my JavaScript file is [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1136236)

This is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView myBrowser;
@SuppressLint({ "JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);

    final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
    = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
    myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new Object(), "AndroidFunction");
    myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/sperm.html");
}

public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
      Context mContext;

         MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
             mContext = c;
         }

         public void showToast(String toast){
             Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         public void openAndroidDialog(){
          AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
          = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
          myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
          myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
          myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
          myDialog.show();
         }

     }
```

And this is the XML file :

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/background">
<WebView
   android:id="@+id/mybrowser"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

As I said this is very basic app.

The style in the html file working good, but the script doesn't run.

I'm new with Javascript so any direction could help.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1 :**

I take the java code for Android from [THIS](http://android-er.blogspot.co.il/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html) guide

There is no connection between the Java code and the HTML file, so Myabe there is a need to change MyJavaScriptInterface class.

Sorry if this confused.

Comment: Add @JavascriptInterface annotation to your MyJavaScriptInterface.

Comment: Where exactly in my code i should add this?

Comment: Try to remove this sentence: @SuppressLint({ "JavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled" })

Comment: If I removed this I've got this error : **None of the methods in the added interface have been annotated with @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface; they will not be visible in API 17**

Comment: Oh,I forgot to tell you that import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface first,then you can use @JavascriptInterface,or else it can not be recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your "sperm.html", it include js file :

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

solution 1 : 
it use inertent when load js, so you have add uses-permission in Android manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

solution 2:
 download  "d3.v3.min.js" and put it in assets folder, then modify "sperm.html"

```
<script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right, After i connected to the internet it works.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<script>
```

with

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

In your HTML file.

Also set the Webchromeclient first, then enable javascript:

```
myBrowser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

The javascript interface is not needed to make the javascript work, it is used to call android functions from the javascript in the webview. To make this work you need to provide addJavascriptInterface with the interface you made.

Example:

```
myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "AndroidFunction");
```

If that doesn't work, can you add the javascript code?

Comment: That doesn't work, and you can see the JS from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1136236)

Comment: edited my answer, can you try the set the WebChromeClient before you setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

Comment: I tried, doesn't work. look at the question i edit it. maybe the solution is there.

Comment: Edited my answer again. Replace <script> above yout javascript with <script type="text/javascript">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
  @JavascriptInterface
    public void MyJavaScriptInterface {
```

OR

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
public void MyJavaScriptInterface {
```

You need to add this annotation to your user-defined javascript interface after API level 16.

Comment: he write me this error : The annotation @JavascriptInterface is disallowed for this location

Comment: You can not put `@JavascriptInterface` above class name. You need to put it above a function name.

Answer (score 0):

try to add WebChromeClient to your webview and enable javascript

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

Comment: add this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> as you are using link outside your mobile from internet